# Configure EMR Hadoop Yarn from CLI

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, emr

I am looking for an efficient way to modify both the `mapred-site.xml` and the `yarn-site.xml` in my configuration file for Hadoop on AWS EMR. I can achieve this manually using `vim` to edit it however I was hoping there was a way that was more efficient, perhaps through the CLI or even Python. All my searches online yield nothing, except [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34666416/get-a-yarn-configuration-from-commandline) but it doesn't really answer my question. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You may configure applications at cluster creation time by following http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-configure-apps.html